# Continuous functions in Topologies

Tags: calculus, general-topology, continuity

I'm having quite some difficulty finding continuous functions between topologies. 
Find a continuous function $f:\Bbb{R}_{cocountable} \rightarrow \Bbb{R}_{ususal}$
I'm not sure maybe something that takes open intervals (a,b) to $(a,b) \cap \Bbb{Q}$

Find a continuous function from $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{T}_7) \ to \  \mathbb{R}_{usual}$
In this case I think the only function that would work is the constant function f(x) = 7

Is there a general way to approach questions like these.

Comment: (1) There must be more restrictions to make the problem interesting. Given any two nonempty sets $X,Y$ I can always write down a continuous map $f\colon X \to Y$ by just picking a constant function. (2) What is $\mathcal{T}_7$?

Comment: to find a continuous function you can always pick a constant function

Comment: $\mathcal{T_7}$ is the particular point topology, so a set in the topology is only open if it contains 7. How about finding continuous functions other than 7.

Comment: @jia what about a function $f$ such that $f(q)=7$ for all $q\in\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: in the first case only the constant functions are continuous, and in the second the continuous functions are characterized by the previous property

Comment: The only continuous functions from $\Bbb R$ with the co-countable topology to $\Bbb R$ with the usual topology are the constant functions. Suppose that $f:\Bbb R_{\text{co-countable}}\to\Bbb R$ is not constant. There are $x,y\in\Bbb R$ such that $f(x)\ne f(y)$. Let $U$ and $V$ be disjoint open nbhds of $f(x)$ and $f(y)$, respectively. Then $f^{-1}[U]$ and $f^{-1}[V]$ are disjoint non-empty open sets in $\Bbb R_{\text{co-countable}}$, which is impossible. Thus, $f$ must be constant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The co-countable topology on the reals is [hyperconnected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperconnected_space), which means that every two non-empty pair of open sets intersect:

Suppose $U,V$ are open and non-empty. This means that $\mathbb{R}\setminus U$ and $\mathbb{R}\setminus V$ are both at most countable. So $\mathbb{R} \setminus (U \cap V) = (\mathbb{R}\setminus U) \cup (\mathbb{R}\setminus V)$ is at most countable, so $U \cap V$ cannot be empty, or the reals would be countable.

Now, if $X$ is hyperconnected and $Y$ is Hausdorff, every continuous function from $X$ to $Y$ is constant: if not there are $x \neq y$ in $X$ with $f(x) \neq f(y)$. By virtue of $Y$ being Hausdorff we have disjoint open sets $U$ and $V$ with $f(x) \in U, f(y) \in V$. But then $x \in f^{-1}[U], y \in f^{-1}[V]$, so both $f^{-1}[U]$ and $f^{-1}[V]$ are non-empty, both sets are open by continuity of $f$ and $f^{-1}[U] \cap f^{-1}[V] = f^{-1}[U \cap V] = f^{-1}[\emptyset] = \emptyset$. This contradicts hyperconnectedness of $X$.

So the only continuous functions from the co-countable reals to the usual reals are constant. But it's quite rare to be able to make such an analysis of continuity between spaces.

The second question is about $\mathcal{T}_7$ which I think is the included point topology with respect to $7$ on $\mathbb{R}$, where the open sets are the empty set and all sets containing $7$.

If $f$ is a continuous function to the usual reals, consider $U = \mathbb{R}\setminus \{f(7)\}$, which is open in the usual reals. So $f^{-1}[U]$ must be open, but by definition it does not contain the special point $7$, so it must be empty, the only other open set. So *no* point of $\mathbb{R}$ can map to another point than $f(7)$, which just says (again) that $f$ must be constant.

The point of this exercise, I think, is to practice the inverse images of open sets are open definition of continuity, using these special topologies as test cases.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning co-countable topology:

Suppose that $f$ is a continuous function with $f\left(x\right)<f\left(y\right)$.

Then $f\left(x\right)<a<f\left(y\right)$ for some $a\in\mathbb{R}$
and $f^{-1}\left(\left(-\infty,a\right]\right)$ and $f^{-1}\left(\left[a,\infty\right)\right)$
are closed, and do not equalize $\varnothing$ of $\mathbb{R}$.

The sets cover the uncountable $\mathbb{R}$ so it cannot be that
both are countable.

A contradiction is found and we conclude that $f$ must be constant.

Conversely every constant function is continuous.